# Javascript file is not loaded properly

Tags: css, html, angular

I have a nice html, css [template](http://utgame.freetzi.com/) (source code [here](https://github.com/salman-/HTML-template)).

I am going to use this template in my angular2 app (source code [here](https://github.com/salman-/angular2-template)).

I got the html template out of [this](https://github.com/akivaron/miminium) repository (`index.html`).

**My problem is in the angular2 source code**

1. You need to `clone` the angular source.
2. Run `npm install`
3. Run `ng serve`

Unfortunatly, it seems that the `<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>` in `index.html` is not added properly. Although, there is no error in the console, **the left menu is broken**. I know that this problem occurs when **main.js** is not fit.

Here is the **correct** html page:

[image: correct page]

Here is the angular page (**broken** header and menu):

[image: broken page]

The codes are identical, but I have decomposed the html template into 3 components (header, menu, and app (main content)).

Comment: Check your HTML comments from line 130 in the html file. They're not closed properly so it's breaking the tags coming after.

Comment: and when you open the js file being served does it opens correctly? maybe something to do with the CLRF endings or charset being different if served by ng serve?

Comment: put some custom function and try to call it from the console

Comment: I got your app working, but holly molly, a lot of issues. I will post the complete solution shortly and I'll make a PR against your repository.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to figure out what happened with your CSS, I took the original template, converted it to Angular 2 with the angular-cli, and fixed the CSS issues. It all works now, and the complete source is at https://github.com/Boyan-Kostadinov/angular2-miminium

Comment: The tool I used to validate your CSS to get it to work is at https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input

Comment: It means I cloned your code, made the changes I described, and now you can merge them into your code. Go to the PR (pull request) link in the answer.

Comment: it still does not work. When i push the cross it should close the left hand side menu. Also, the sub-menus of dashboard should not be shown at first. like this template http://utgame.freetzi.com/

Comment: Right, like I said, I didn't fix the CSS because that file is way too giant. I did make the whole thing compile and run.

Comment: The css comes from this project, it is not the thing i made 
https://github.com/akivaron/miminium

Comment: Alright, let me check that out, I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

When you broke apart `index.html` it's likely that you also altered some file paths.

The relative path would go from `src="assets/js/main.js"` to something like `src="../assets/js/main.js"`.

Prepending `../` to the path will back out of the current directory to the next level up. As you have it now, the browser is looking for the `assets` directory in what I assume you have compartmentalized as an `htmlComponents` directory.

Consider using the absolute path to `main.js`, at least to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with the same file. In my case, I have a complicated application that is developed in stages. I installed my Angular seed in a subdirectory. Because of my file structure, when I run `npm start`, the live server that is started has bad relative link locations. For example, in the screen shot below, you will see that the application is trying to find `style.css` at http://localhost:3000/medface/RecordWriter/styles.css; however, it should be looking at http://localhost:3000/styles.css, because the root of the web server that was created by `npm start` is at /medface/RecordWriter/.

[image]

With respect to your project. The key to finding the problem with your link is to open the developer panel and inspect the actual network request. If you share a screen shot, we may be able to help you inspect your instance with more insight.

**What Worked for Me**

In my case, I reconfigured my local web server to handle any unserved pages in the Angular2 folder and return the index instead. When I run `npm start`, I close the browser page that opens and use my regular web server. Instead of viewing my application on **localhost:3000**, I view my application at **localhost/medface/RecordWriter/** (which is equivalent to **localhost:80/medface/RecordWriter**).

The down side to my makeshift approach is that the page must be refreshed before changes appear, but it loads all resources predictably and reliably, and allows my Angular2 code to run in conjunction with some of the older code base in other areas of the website that have not been converted to Angular2. Regardless, this may work for you also.